# How deploy a Play Application in Apache Server

Tags: apache, playframework-2.0

I want to use apache as a front end proxy server for the application created by Play Framework 2.2. I did following things in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName test.app
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

and added following line in host file

```
127.0.0.1       test.app
```

Then For the URL http://test.app/ it gives 500 error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, admin@domain.in and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

For the URL http://test.app:9000/login it render my application home page.
But I don`t know what is missing.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks...

Comment: Check the apache's error log first, there should be some clue in it...

Comment: Thank You, I fix that problem by adding the line,           LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so